# Does anyone know if ExcelPackage is still in development?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, .net-framework, c#, microsoft-excel

I was looking for something to read excel in and I found this [excel package](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/)  I am wondering if it is still under development as I don't see it support excel 2010.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), it's regularly updated

> This project started with the source from ExcelPackage

Take a look also at [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c) for more suggestions

Comment: Do you have any examples how to use it when importing an excel sheet through a webpage and want to extract the values?

Comment: Ah I think I found something I need in the sample project. I will look into that more.

Comment: So I been looking at it and I can't figure out how to figure out how many rows are in the file and how many cells are in each row.

Comment: @chobo2: I think this isn't in the scope of this question anymore. If you're creating a (web)application and are having problems with it then I suggest you create a new question in Stackoverflow with the details